# .NET MVC - Many-To-Many Relationship with Find or Create.- Duplicating records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to achieve a functionality very similar to what we have here on SO - The Tagging System. I enter tags, it looks if they exist - and if not, they are being created an associated with the post via a Join Table (Many-To-Many).

It works like this: The User enters the Tags, in a ", "-Seperated Value (The TagList). I split the TagList with a RegEx to extract the different tags - I try to look the tag up in the Database. And If it doesnt exist, I create it.

So far, this is what I have:

#### Recipe.cs

```
public class Recipe
{
    [Key]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public int Serving { get; set; }
    public string Instructions { get; set; }
    public int PrepTime { get; set;}
    public int CookingTime { get; set; }
    public IList<Wine> Wines { get; set; }
    public IList<Pairing> Pairings { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<UsedIngredient> UsedIngredients { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string TagList { get; set; }
    public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; } 
}
```

#### Tag.cs

```
public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }      
}
```

#### The Join Table

CreateTable(

```
"dbo.TagRecipes",
        c => new
            {
                Tag_TagId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                Recipe_RecipeId = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.Tag_TagId, t.Recipe_RecipeId })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Tags", t => t.Tag_TagId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Recipes", t => t.Recipe_RecipeId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.Tag_TagId)
        .Index(t => t.Recipe_RecipeId);
```

#### TagRepo - FindOrCreate Method

```
public Tag FindOrCreateTag(string tagName)
{
    Tag tag = context.Tags.Where(t => t.Name == tagName).Include("Recipes").FirstOrDefault();
    if (tag == null)
    {
         tag = new Tag
         {
             Name = tagName,
             Recipes = new List<Recipe>()                        
          };
          context.Tags.Add(tag);
     }           
    return tag;
}
```

#### RecipeRepo - GetTagList

```
private IList<String> GetTagList(string tagString)
{
    IList<string> tagList = new List<string>(Regex.Split(tagString, @"\,\s*"));
    return tagList;
}
```

#### RecipeRepo - AssignTags

```
public void AssignTags(Recipe recipe, string tagString)
{
    if (recipe.Tags == null)
        recipe.Tags = new List<Tag>();
    IList<string> tags = GetTagList(tagString);
    foreach (string tagName in tags)
    {
        Tag tag = tagRepository.FindOrCreateTag(tagName);
        if (tag.Recipes == null)
           tag.Recipes = new List<Recipe>();
        if (!tag.Recipes.Any(r => r.RecipeId == recipe.RecipeId))
           tag.Recipes.Add(recipe);
        if (recipe.Tags.All(t => t.TagId != tag.TagId))
           recipe.Tags.Add(tag);
     }   
}
```

And in the end, Im calling this.

#### RecipeRepo - Update

```
public bool Update(Recipe recipe)
{
    if (recipe.TagList != null)
        AssignTags(recipe, recipe.TagList);

     Recipe dbEnt = context.Recipes.Find(recipe.RecipeId);
     context.Entry(dbEnt).CurrentValues.SetValues(recipe);

     return Save();
}
```

What happens is - It takes the String, splits it up correctly - but after that, things seem to go south a bit. Instead of simply assigning the new tag, it duplicates the Recipe Object.

Whats is it, that Im missing?

Comment: Instead why don't you add one more identity field in your connection table. It is better to split many to many into two one to many relations. Queries look nice and it is easy to query complicated queries.

Answer (score 0):

Object that is retrieved from the context (such as a result of `Find`) should be 'Attached' before it has changes tracking capabilities, and is possible to be updated in the DB. 
You should also mark it as 'Modified'.

For example, a proper update method should be something like:

```
public bool Update(Recipe recipe)
{
    if (recipe.TagList != null)
        AssignTags(recipe, recipe.TagList);

     Recipe dbEnt = context.Recipes.Find(recipe.RecipeId);

     if (context.Entry(dbEnt).State == EntityState.Detached)
     {
         context.Set<Recipe>().Attach(dbEnt);
     }
     context.Entry(dbEnt).State = EntityState.Modified;

     context.Entry(dbEnt).CurrentValues.SetValues(recipe);

     return Save();
}
```

If you would like to make a generic update function, it should look as follows:

```
public void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
{
    if (context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entityToUpdate);
    }
    context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```